# Goto previous files/documents shortcut in Netbeans 7.x

Tags: netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut in Netbeans to go to previous files/documents (actually in tabs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I was asking is very useful, I would like to answer it myself as nobody gave an answer.
1. Open Netbeans
2. Open Preferences
3. In **Keymap** tab search for "***previous***" keyword in Search field as shown in screenshot below:
[image]

Set your preferable shortcut and that's all!